# linq to sql select new keyword and assign column alias name

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

i wants to assign column alias to another column in linq to sql select new keyword my code is

```
var query=from d in db.tblAttributeDatas
          select new
                 {
                    a=d.strValue,
                    b=a    
                 };
```

but compiler give me error.

> can not resolved symbol a

.

Comment: can not resolve symbol a

Comment: There is no `a`. There is an a field on the thing you are `new`ing up, but you can't access that until you finish `new`ing it. There is however a `d`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you can't do this because of the nature of object initializers (which is: initializing objects using the object literal notation `{ ... }`).

This simple line of code...

```
var x = new { a = 1, b = 2 };
```

...is executed in IL code as...

```
<>f__AnonymousType0<System.Int32,System.Int32>..ctor
```

So you see that the anonymous type is created having a two-parameter constructor. Suppose this constructor would be visible as...

```
class X
{
    public X(int a, int b) { }
}
```

It's obvious you can't call this constructor by

```
var x = new X(1, a);
```

You must supply two values. One constructor argument can't "borrow" the value of the other argument.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use alias that way.

You have to do it using `let` this way:

```
var query=from d in db.tblAttributeDatas
          let str = d.strValue // hold value here
          select new
                 {
                    a=str,  // now assign here
                    b=str     
                 };
```

Comment: but my basic question is can we assign alias to another alias because i need this

Comment: @raja you cant what i see

Comment: i can't imagine any situation when this answer is not enough

Answer (score 0):

assign the same value to b .. there is no harm..

```
var query = from d in db.tblAttributeDatas
            select new
            {
                a = d.strValue,
                b = d.strValue    
            };
```

Comment: but my basic question is can we assign alias to another alias because i need this